# How should I validate a coupon in Laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I have an AJAX request coming from my checkout page that gives the user entered coupon code. This passes into my controller like so:

```
public function attachCoupon(AttachCouponRequest $request)
{        
    $response = ShopHelper::checkCoupon($request->coupon);

    return Response::json($response);
}
```

My 'checkCoupon' function is loaded in from a helper class and looks like so:

```
public static function checkCoupon($code) 
{
    $coupon = Coupon::where('code',$code)->get();

    if ($coupon->isEmpty()) {
        $response = ['valid' => false, 'message' => 'Coupon code not recognised'];
    } elseif ( isset($coupon->end_date) && $coupon->end_date < Carbon::now()) {
        $response = ['valid' => false, 'message' => 'Sorry, that coupon has expired.'];
    } elseif ( isset($coupon->start_date) && $coupon->start_date > Carbon::now()) {
        $response = ['valid' => false, 'message' => 'Sorry, that coupon is not yet valid.'];
    } elseif ( isset($coupon->status) && $coupon->status === 'inactive') {
        $response = ['valid' => false, 'message' => 'Sorry, that coupon is inactive.'];
    } else {
        $response = ['valid' => true, 'message' => 'Coupon applied successfully!.'];
    }

    return($response);
}
```

**This seems very un-laravel-like, is there a neater way to do this? Can I put this into my FormRequest class 'AttachCouponRequest'? Should I be using a Service Provider?**

Please help me make this more elegant.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, you're calling get() with Eloquent, but the method name indicates you're just checking if it's a valid coupon.

So, why not change the query, so that you apply the filters on the coupon itself and return a generic success / failed response?

For instance:

```
$coupon = Coupon::where('code',$code)
    ->where('end_date', '>=', Carbon::now())
    ->where('start_date', '<=', Carbon::now())
    ->where('status', '!=', 'inactive')
    ->count();

if (! $count) {
    return ['valid' => false, 'message' => 'Sorry, that coupon is not valid.'];
}

return ['valid' => true, 'message' => 'Coupon applied successfully!'];
```

You could then utilize query scopes, so that you could do things like this, to improve readability:

```
$coupon = Coupon::where('code', $code)->onlyActive()->get();
```

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Completely forgot query scopes. I'll that to my model for a quick and easy reference.